# Back-transforming results of multiple linear regression

Tags: linear-regression

I transformed dependent variable by raising to a power of $0.4$.  When the original data is plotted on the back-transformed $y^{1/0.4}$ predicted results, the intercept is substantially larger than zero & gradient lower than $1$.  Even by adding $\sigma^{1/0.4}$ to the back-transformed data does not substantially improve it.  Anyone have ideas on what more may be done? Regards, Michael.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you fitted a model of the form

$$y^{0.4} = a x + b$$

Solving for $y$,

$$y = (a x + b)^{1/0.4}$$

Comment: Thankyou Daniel - I actually transformed the y, not the x.  So it's of the form y^0.4 = ax_1 + bx_2 + c .  On back-transforming the predictions as y^(1/0.4) and plotting against observations, I am not getting quite a 0 intercept and gradient of 1.  Any ideas?

Comment: Updated answer.